# Intuition about ADHM construction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-equations, yang-mills, instantons, solitons

I'm trying to understand reasons, **why self-dual Yang-Mills equation can be reduced to algebraic equations**. It's seem like a miracle.

In article [Construction of Instanton and Monopole Solutions and Reciprocity](http://inspirehep.net/record/13934?ln=en) authors mentioned some motivation for ADHM:

> This construction is based on 
>   the observation of Ward that **Penrose’s twistor theory** can be used to establish a 
>   correspondence between self-dual gauge fields and certain **analytic vector bundles**. In 
>   the original proof of the construction, the analytic vector bundle, corresponding 
>   to a given self-dual gauge field, was constructed using a **sequence of vector spaces
>   defined in terms of sheaf cohomology groups**. One of the central ideas of twistor 
>   theory is the **correspondence between such groups and the spaces of solutions of 
>   covariant differential equations** (such as the Dirac equation and the Laplace equation, 
>   as well as other less familiar ones formulated in ordinary space, Euclidean or 
>   Minkowski as appropriate).

Is it possible to understand from more intuitive point of view or illustrate in some simple examples?

Is it only specific of self-dual Yang-Mills equation, or used in another equations? Could you provide some examples?

I will be grateful for any suggestions.